# if constexpr and requires-expression for ad-hoc concepts checking

Tags: c++, c++20, requires-expression

Let's say, given C++17's `if constexpr` and Concepts TS (for instance, in recent gcc versions), we'd like to check if a type in a template function has a nested type:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { using Bar = int; };

template<typename T>
void doSmth(T)
{
    if constexpr (requires { typename T::Bar; })
        std::cout << "has nested! " << typename T::Bar {} << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "no nested!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doSmth(Foo {});
    //doSmth(0);
}
```

The documentation for concepts is scarce, so I might have got it wrong, but seems like that's it (and the live example is on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QIBdPOsxSVK5AD9r)).

Now let's consider what should happen when uncommenting the other `doSmth` call. It seems reasonable to expect that the requires-clause would evaluate to `false`, and the `else` branch of the `if constexpr` will be taken. Contrary to that, gcc makes this a hard error:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'void doSmth(T) [with T = int]':
prog.cc:17:13:   required from here
prog.cc:8:5: error: 'int' is not a class, struct, or union type
     if constexpr (requires { typename T::Bar; })
     ^~
```

Is that a bug in gcc, or is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: Note that using a separate class (non-primitive) also produces an hard error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QIBdPOsxSVK5AD9r

Comment: AFAIK gcc's concepts implementation is based on Concepts TS, which has only been accepted with some modifications, including restricting where a `requires` clause is used. Allowing this has been proposed separately in [P0266](https://wg21.link/p0266). I don't think we can answer your question yet.

Comment: @Rakete1111 well, something along the lines of `requires { requires std::is_same_v<T, int> }` works as expected (I'm still not that familiar with the syntax, so I might write it wrong) in this context

Comment: My question seems related https://stackoverflow.com/q/53493715/893406 your answer is that this hard error is by design.

Comment: It started to work with the latest GCC version: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QIBdPOsxSVK5AD9r

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Concepts [issue 3](http://cplusplus.github.io/concepts-ts/ts-complete.html#3) ("Allow *requires-expression*s in more contexts") was given WP status in June. And judging by the current looks of [[expr.prim.req]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req), in particular p6:

> The substitution of template arguments into a *requires-expression* may result in the formation of invalid types or expressions in its requirements or the violation of the semantic constraints of those requirements. In such cases, the *requires-expression* evaluates to `false`; it does not cause the program to be ill-formed.

I'd say your code is fine, and GCC hasn't implemented the resolution of issue 3 properly.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this syntax is fine! The problem is that the failure inside the `requires` expression causes a full hard failure, and if one writes something like requiring that `T` is `Foo` using `std::is_same_v`, it works just fine. Sadly, I don't know standardese enough to figure out if this follows from the standard and the proposals already, or whether special attention should be paid to it.

Comment: @0xd34df00d My bad, I didn't read the question properly. I might have a look later, but for now it seems like that is certainly not a problem (would defeat the purpose of requires expressions themselves).

Comment: @0xd34df00d Adjusted the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I should have read the paragraph you originally referred more thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example of using `concept` inside `if constexpr` for checking if a type has the method *foo* with a specific return type *T* provided as a template parameter:

```
template<class P, class T>
concept Fooable = requires(P p) {
    requires std::same_as<decltype(p.foo()), T>;
};

template<typename T>
void printIsFooable(const auto& p) {
    if constexpr( Fooable<decltype(p), T> ) {
        std::cout << "fooable <" << typeid(T).name() << ">" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "not fooable <" << typeid(T).name() << ">" << std::endl;
    }
}

struct MyFoo {
    void foo() const {}
};

int main() {
    printIsFooable<void>(MyFoo{}); // fooable <v>
    printIsFooable<int>(MyFoo{});  // not fooable <i>
    printIsFooable<void>(int{});   // not fooable <v>
}
```

Code compiles with C++20 [in GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/jPZDrL) and [in Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/hK6x77).

Comment: Couldn't you write the concept simply as: `template<class P, class T>
concept Fooable = std::same_as<decltype(P{}.foo()), T>;`?

Comment: @303 your version requires P to have an empty constructor.

Comment: You could still wrap it in a `std::declval` when deemed necessary but I can see the alternative becoming less appealing.

Answer (score 5):

It works starting from C++2a and gcc 10:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo { using Bar = char; };

template<typename T> void doSmth(T)
{
    if constexpr (requires { typename T::Bar; })
        std::cout << "T has Bar of type: " << typeid(typename T::Bar).name() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "T does not have Bar" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    doSmth(Foo {});
    doSmth(1);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/qH34tI6oRJ3Ck7Mm